# Nagios: Not able to write Performance data into file

Tags: nagios, graphite

I am trying to make the communication between Nagios and Graphite but couldn't able to write Nagios performance data to the file.

I am referring below mentioned sites:
http://nagios.manubulon.com/traduction/docs25en/perfdata.html
http://nagios.manubulon.com/traduction/docs14en/xpdfile.html

To configure nagios.conf
http://nagios.manubulon.com/traduction/docs25en/configmain.html#host_perfdata_file

Comment: Could you specify the exact issue or do you really expect people to go through those documents?

Answer (score 0):

Please give some details on the perfdata file.
Make shure the file is writeable by the user your nagios is running with.

For Example:

If you use /usr/local/nagios/var/host-perfdata.dat to store your host performance data and your nagios is running with the user nagios the permission would look like:

```
-rw-rw-r-- nagios nagios host-perfdata
```